# Htaccess causes redirects chain

Tags: .htaccess

Recently, we switched from `www.example.de`to `www.example.com/de`. Unfortunately some minor and bigger issue occurred with the `.htaccess`.

**Issue**

**Redirect chain**

1. `www.example.de/path` redirects to  `www.example.com/de/path` an then to `www.example.com/de/path/`

How do I remove the unecessary redirect?

2. Every blog article gets redirected to `http` and then to `https`.

`https://www.example.de/blog/article` redirects to `http://example.com/blog/article/` then to `https://example.com/blog/article/` and finally to https://example.com/de/blog/article/

The redirect to `http` only occurs for the blog. The rest off the website doesnt redirect to http.
It seems to me that the htaccess is ignored by requests to the blog. I don`t know what I did wrong!

`htaccess www.example.de:`

```
SetEnv PHPRC /home/customer/www/example.de/public_html/php.ini
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/de/$1 [R=301,L]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

`htaccess www.example.com/de:`

```
SetEnv PHPRC /home/customer/www/example.com/public_html/php.ini


# BEGIN rlrssslReallySimpleSSL rsssl_version[5.1.0]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Possible Solution**

Can I add this to solve the Issue with the trailing slash?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com/%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Where do `example.de` and `example.com` resolve to in relation to each other?

Comment: Do you have any other `.htaccess` files? In the `blog` subdirectory perhaps? (I'm assuming this is a physical subdirectory?) There is no HTTPS to HTTP redirect in the code you posted - so you need to resolve/fix that elsewhere.

Comment: @MrWhite you were right. There was an additional htaccess file in the subdirectory blog. Thank you for the help with that. I just took this over and it would have cost me a lot of time since I am not familiar with htaccess.

Comment: So, is your issue now resolved?

Comment: I have still the issue that all URL request without trailing slash have one additional redirect. The redirect gets to the site without trialing slash and then to right site with trailing slash.
Do I have to add an RewriteCond which redirects all request without / at the end to an site with / ?